# Multithreading - how to invoke Action

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, action, invoke, begininvoke

I have some menu popup with action buttons. This is popup so it is made in new thread. I add event to created buttons something like this:

```
private StdProcedure m_ToInvoke;

public void AddButton()
{
    Button myChildTempButton = new Button();
    myChildTempButton.ItemClick += new ItemClickEventHandler((x, y) => 
    { 
       HidePopup(); m_ToInvoke = myOpp.Procedure; 
    });
 }
```

StdProcedure is delegate

```
 public delegate void StdProcedure();
```

And after close event:

```
 protected override void OnPopupClosed()
 {
    base.OnPopupClosed();
    if (m_ToInvoke != null) m_ToInvoke.Invoke();
 }
```

That doesn't work correctly. Sometime invoked operations stopped my another thread and I don't understand how it's works.

My question is what is the different between:

```
m_ToInvoke()
m_ToInvoke.Invoke()
m_ToInvoke.BeginInvoke()
m_ToInvoke.DynamicInvoke()
```

and what should I use here?

For me first and second is the same in effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `m_ToInvoke()` is just C# syntactic sugar for `m_ToInvoke.Invoke()`
- `m_ToInvoke.Invoke()` executes the delegate synchronously, in the same thread
- `m_ToInvoke.BeginInvoke()` schedules the delegate for invocation in a thread-pool thread; the returned `IAsyncResult` can be used to wait for it to complete, and you can also pass in a callback
- `m_ToInvoke.DynamicInvoke()` is the only one of these methods to be declared by [`Delegate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke) - it's similar to calling it by reflection, in that there's no compile-time safety for the number/type of the arguments etc.

Note that calling `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` on a delegate is very different to calling `Dispatcher.Invoke/BeginInvoke` or `Control.Invoke/BeginInvoke`, which are to do with invoking a delegate within the UI thread for a WPF/WinForms app - although again, the `Invoke` version is synchronous and `BeginInvoke` is asynchronous.